# Can I use JPA annotations in a non-EE standalone environment?

Tags: java, jpa, annotations, jpa-2.0, openjpa

I'd like to do some rapid prototyping with OpenJPA and I would like to use JPA annotations in my classes. I would like to run standalone (like from a `main` method). Can this be done?

So far I was able to run standalone but I had to use a mapping XML file that I pointed to from persistence.xml. The annotations were not being picked up automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [official web page](http://openjpa.apache.org/):

> Apache OpenJPA is a Java persistence project at The Apache Software Foundation that can be used as a **stand-alone POJO persistence layer** or integrated into any Java EE compliant container and many other lightweight frameworks, such as Tomcat and Spring.

Check out the [Getting started tutorial](http://openjpa.apache.org/getting-started.html) to find examples.

Comment: Is enhancement mandatory when running standalone with annotations? With a mapping XML file, I am able to run with unenhancement supported. Perhaps enhancement code is what parses the annotations.